# How to send "truncated" model to thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have table in thymeleaf, where I want to show only two fields of basic model. What is the best way to send only some field of model: create new class named **ContractListView** or create e.g. a list of map with necessary fields?

Controller method:

```java
        contracts.add(new Contract("123", new Date(), 300.80));
        model.addAttribute("contracts", contracts);
        return "contracts";
```

Template contracts.html:

```html
 <tr th:each="contract : ${contracts}">
    <td th:text="${contract.serial}"></td>
    <td th:text="${#dates.format(contract.date, 'dd.MM.yyyy')}"></td>
  </tr>
```

As you can see, I don't need the third field (value 300.80) in the template. So how do you solve this?

Comment: Why is it necessary to specifically exclude the field? Whats the problem with it being available and unused? Give us some more context please

Comment: I want to know universal approach to solve that  kind of problem, for example in case there are much more extra data than used data.

Comment: Please explain what you mean with `that kind of problem`. As you put it into your model thymeleaf will probably use reflection to access the objects fields. Thus you need a completely new object containing only the necessary fields. Normally you would do something thats called a projection: create an interface with only the getters that should be exposed, implement it in the object which has all fields and downcast it before returning. But as I said, thymeleaf will probably ignore that (unless configurable to only use the public function of the interface type, not the underlying type)

Comment: Oh, thank you, @roookeee. I have understood that thymeleaf page makes on server, and extra data won't be send to client. I though that all fields will be send to client.

Comment: Correct. Glad I could help :)